# Where is the property in self-defining function?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about Self-Defining Function.

```
var scareMe = function(){
  console.log("Boo!");
  var instance = this;
  scareMe = function(){
    console.log("Double Boo!");
    return instance;
  }
}
scareMe.prototype.nothing = true;
var un1 = new scareMe();
console.log(un1.nothing); //true
scareMe.prototype.everything = true;
var un2 = new scareMe();
console.log(un1 === un2); //true
```

It works as I expected.

```
console.log(un2.everything); //undefined
```

Where can I get the 'everything' property?

Comment: Note that only one instance is created here, the second call to *scareMe* returns a reference to the same object created in the first call (via closure to *instance*), so *un1* and *un2* reference the same object, hence why `un1 === un2` is true.

Answer (score 2):

it won't work because once `scareMe` is called, you are overriding `scareMe` with another function when you try to change the prototype after the initial call you are actually changing the prototype of the second method not the first method with which you had created the instance. So changes to the prototype is not reflected in your instance.

---

One possible solution is to override the prototype of the second object with the first one

```
var scareMe = function () {
    console.log("Boo!");
    var instance = this,
        proto = scareMe.prototype;
    scareMe = function () {
        console.log("Double Boo!");
        return instance;
    }
    scareMe.prototype = proto;
}
scareMe.prototype.nothing = true;
var un1 = new scareMe();
console.log('nothing', un1.nothing); //true
scareMe.prototype.everything = true;
var un2 = new scareMe();
console.log(un1 === un2); //true
console.log('everything', un1.everything); //true
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6h4d2vkg/)

---

Another way to write the same could be something like

```
var scareMe = (function () {
    var instance;
    return function () {
        if (instance) {
            return instance;
        }
        instance = this;

    }
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6h4d2vkg/2/)